# Spring-Integration: error-channel: how to use multiple error-channel declarations in a workflow?

Tags: spring, exception, spring-integration, declarative

I'm trying to figure out a general strategy for exception handling within Spring-Integration workflows.

I'm using an `error-channel` attribute on the `int-http:inbound-gateway` and that works fine for errors that I encounter in the workflow.

```xml
<int-http:inbound-gateway 
      ...
      error-channel = "general-errors"
      ...
      />

<int:channel id="general-errors" />
<int:chain input-channel = "general-errors" >
     ....
</int:chain>
```

In this case, when there is an exception, the steps in the `general-errors` chain create the return message.

But I also was looking at having some specific error handling for inner flows in the workflow, for instance for calls to external services.

```xml
<int:chain>
    <si:gateway request-channel="transformForRequest" />
    <si:gateway request-channel="httpCall"            error-channel="httpError" />
    <si:gateway request-channel="transformResponse"   />
</int:chain>

<int:channel id="httpCall" />
<int-http:outbound-gateway request-channel="httpCall" 
...
/>

<int:channel id="httpError" />
<int:chain request-channel="httpError" >
   ... do special error processing for http call ...
</int:chain>
```

I've tried this and I discovered that, upon an exception in the call to the `int-http:outbound-gateway`which then calls to `httpError` chain, the workflow processing continues at `transformResponse`.  What I would like to happen is to return the error payload and headers from the `http:inbound-gateway` at that point.

Is there an different approach that would allow me to apply specific exception processing within inner flows?  Or perhaps I can force a return to the `http:inbound-gateway` via `replyChannel` header from within the `httpError` chain?

Thanks for any help/pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not fully clear what you are asking, but it feels like you'd like to return some custom payload from the `httpError` sub-flow, but return it immediately into an `<int-http:inbound-gateway>` in the beginning of the flow. If that is the case, then it is not possible. You return something from the `httpError` sub-flow back to that `<si:gateway request-channel="httpCall">`. Since it is just plain return it is treated as a reply and therefore it send to whatever goes after. In your case `<si:gateway request-channel="transformResponse" />`. The payload is just out of the messaging system scope. You made your flow go on, so it will be independently of the payload.

Of course your can interfere into the logic based on the returned payload via `<router>` and already there decide to continue the flow downstream or come back to the inbound gateway in the beginning.

No, the `replyChannel` won't help you from the `httpError` sub-flow. Just because a `<si:gateway>` creates its own `replyChannel` within its context. Therefore coming back to this channel will just bring a reply payload back to the `<si:gateway>`, not an HTTP Inbound Gateway in the beginning. The bigger problem that even an explicit `reply-channel` configuration for that HTTP Inbound Gateway won't help here. It's consuming logic in the end relies on a `replyChannel` header anyway. Which in our case is a `replyChannel` for that `<si:gateway>` in the middle.

So, if you want to have a custom `httpError` and bring its result back to the HTTP Inbound Gateway immediately and don't want to have a router just after that `httpCall`, then look into throwing some custom exception which you would handle respectively in the top-level `general-errors` for HTTP Inbound Gateway.

Everything is OK with what you have so far - only the problem that your requirement cannot wonk just as is without some extra effort. This is something similar to what we could do with just plain Java when we call one function from another and would like to return immediately without going for the next function.

Comment: Custom exception thrown from ```httpError``` .. I will give that a shot, thanks.

Comment: I was able to get something to work using your suggestion. I added a ```throw``` to a custom ```Exception``` at the end of the "inner" ```error-channel handler```, attaching the ```Message<?>``` created by the handler to the custom ```Exception```.  In the "outer" ```error-channel``` which is invoked by the custom ```Exception```, I also needed to copy the ```replyChannel``` and ```errorChannel``` from the outer error-handling context.  Seems to be robust but I will continue test.  Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah. Sorry, I forgot to mention that you have to copy/paste request failed message headers to satisfy request-reply pattern in the beginning.